# How to get the name of the shadow(s) for an AWS IoT thing using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I know I can get the description of an IoT thing with [`aws iot describe-thing`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/describe-thing.html), given the name of an IoT thing. And I know I can get the contents of a thing shadow given the name of the shadow with [`aws iot-data get-thing-shadow`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/get-thing-shadow.html).

The `describe-thing` command returns, for example,

```json
{
    "defaultClientId": "MyLightBulb",
    "thingName": "MyLightBulb",
    "thingId": "40da2e73-c6af-406e-b415-15acae538797",
    "thingArn": "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:123456789012:thing/MyLightBulb",
    "thingTypeName": "LightBulb",
    "attributes": {
        "model": "123",
        "wattage": "75"
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

Note that this output does not include the names of any agent shadows(s).

How can I retrieve the name of an IoT thing's shadow if I know the thing's name, so that I can ultimately use `get-thing-shadow` with the name of the shadow to get the shadow's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the shadow for your thing-name by running this [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/list-named-shadows-for-thing.html):

```
aws iot-data list-named-shadows-for-thing --thing-name your-thing
```

and then run the get-thing-shadow by specifying the named shadow (for classic shadow you can ommit `--shadow-name`)

```
aws iot-data get-thing-shadow --thing-name your-thing --shadow-name shadow-name output.txt
```

If you have aws fleet indexing enabled (on your shadow and named shadow), you can retrieve the entire thing information (attributes, thingGroup, connectivity, classic and named shadow) using the `search-index` command:

```
aws iot search-index --index-name "AWS_Things" --query-string "thingName:your-thing-name"
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to note though, at least on my version of the AWS CLI, the `aws iot-data get-thing-shadow` requires an `outfile` argument.

Comment: Yes, I forgot it, I edited the response, please mark it as accepted, you know the game :)

Comment: You updated the wrong command. [`list-named-shadows-for-thing`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/list-named-shadows-for-thing.html) does not require an `outfile` argument, it is the [`get-thing-shadow`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/get-thing-shadow.html) command that does require an `outfile` argument.